# Javascript slideshow web application get really slow

Tags: javascript, html, tizen, tizen-web-app

I have a Tizen TV Web application, which is basically just a regular web application with Javascript and HTML5. The app must display pictures one by one as a slideshow. The pictures are rather large, about 3000px x 2000px png files, and there are about 300 of them.

I load them as they are needed, not all at once.

Problem being that the application is super fast when it starts, but get progressively slower as time goes on. Eventually, it completely freeze as the TV most likely runs out of memory. Also, this app should be running 24/7, but right now we need to restart the TV at least once a day.

I feel like the cache is being filled and is never cleared. I far a I know, there is no way to clear the cache in Javascript. Is there any solutions to this problem ?

Comment: Supposing it is a non-clearing cache problem, did you have a look at the caching phenomenons time-to-live(TTL) or time-to-idle(TTI) -especially the former, for your case.

Comment: This could be one of a million things, depending on the implementation. Maybe Image objects are created and never cleaned up. Maybe image containers are created and appended to your document, but never removed. We do signage using displays on the Tizen platform, which does work - there is something wrong with your implementation. This is however not enough info to go on.